# Can I disable using the mouse wheel to scroll through the hotbar?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

I used to write a script in Macro/Keybind Mod that allows to jump using mouse wheel up. It works, but the mouse wheel can still be used to change the hotbar slot. In «controls» I didn't find option to disable it. How I can do it?

Comment: I don't think it's possible with vanilla minecraft. Maybe you can find another client side mod that lets you change the scroll wheel

Comment: Have you tried https://autohotkey.com ? I assume that with some research, you can prevent mouse wheel events from getting through or maybe prevent any input to Minecraft but instead just send your own and then omit the wheel events. Btw., it would certainly be rather easy to make the jump macro with it on wheel turn, so you'd get all out of one box. AHK is recommendable, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no option to disable this, your best bet would be to contact a mod developer to create a custom mod, or to learn to create this mod yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to do this is to set Scroll Sensitivity to 0% under Settings / Controls / Mouse Settings.

Answer (score 1):

Use X-Mouse Button Control, it does changes the wheel function and does stop scroll hotbar as well.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this is an actual option, but here:

In settings, there is a hotbar up/down selection with “MW UP” and “MW DOWN”. Remove these or set them to another key, like “period” or “left bracket”.

Comment: Yeah it's not there.

Answer (score -1):

I would just go into the settings and set the scroll sensitivity to the lowest possible value of 0.01. Should be good enough, you'd have to scroll *a lot* for it to begin scrolling.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this *technically* not fully disable it? I imagine scrolling would just be *really* slow.